# Displaytag does not recognize struts element

Tags: struts2, displaytag

I'm trying to pass column names as action parameter and use it inside of display tag.
the display:column does not grab any value in value stack, but just print whatever is in title attribute as plain string.

With following code:

```
<display:table name="pList" uid="chartRow" id="sTable" pagesize="10" class="table" requestURI="/some.action">
<s:iterator value="columns" var="column" status="cStatus">
    <display:column title="${column}">
        <s:property value="#attr.sTable[#column]" />
    </display:column>
</s:iterator>
</display:table>
```

I get ${column} as column names for whole table.
Any suggestion?

sturts-2.2
displaytag-1.2

Comment: FYI, I also tried to use s:set without any luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much wasting of my time with jstl, el all that.

<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

resolved my issue.